# Android : Filterable not working on text clear

Tags: android, listview, android-filterable

I have custom listview and I have implemented SearchView to filter data. When we type something for search listview get filter correctly, but when I clear some characters from search text listview doesn't filter data. It remain constant at last search position.

Let me explain with screenshots.

Here, List is not yet filtered. all item are present.
I am searching in two fields of each item(name and description).

[image]

In this screen I have searched from `cam` it shows me correct result.

[image]

I have clear text till c and I am expecting resut should be two item i.e. camera and LED TV.

[image]

Here is my code.

> RateListAdapter.java

```
public class RateListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
public ArrayList<RateList> itemRateList;
public LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ArrayList<RateList> tempList;
CustomFilter filter;

public RateListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RateList> itemRateList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemRateList = itemRateList;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.tempList = itemRateList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemRateList.size();
}

@Override
public RateList getItem(int i) {
    return itemRateList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

class Holder {
    TextView tv_name, tv_description, tv_amount;
    ImageView iv_itemImage;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    Holder h = new Holder();
    RateList rateList = itemRateList.get(i);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_list_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    h.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    h.tv_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    h.tv_amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
    h.iv_itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_itemImage);

    h.tv_name.setText(rateList.Name);
    h.tv_description.setText(rateList.description);
    h.tv_amount.setText("₹ "+rateList.amount);
    Picasso.with(context).load(rateList.image).resize(92,92).into(h.iv_itemImage);

    return convertView;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

private class CustomFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0) {

            constraint=constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            ArrayList<RateList> filters=new ArrayList<RateList>();

            for(int i=0;i<itemRateList.size();i++) {

                if (itemRateList.get(i).Name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
                        itemRateList.get(i).description.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {

                    RateList r = new RateList();
                    r.Name = itemRateList.get(i).Name;
                    r.description= itemRateList.get(i).description;
                    r.id = itemRateList.get(i).id;
                    r.image = itemRateList.get(i).image;
                    r.amount = itemRateList.get(i).amount;

                    filters.add(r);
                }
            }
            results.count = filters.size();
            results.values = filters;
        } else {
            results.count=itemRateList.size();
            results.values=itemRateList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
        itemRateList=(ArrayList<RateList>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

searchview code of

> BookingFrament.java

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {
            rateListAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchQuery);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are modifying the `itemRateList`

Check this method:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
    itemRateList=(ArrayList<RateList>) results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I will suggest to store the result in a separate arrayList and use it in for you adapter class.

Due to the above result being updated in the original `itemRateList`, so next time when the `performFiltering` method is invoked. You are iterating just the previous result and NOT the original list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't cleared yet what changes I have to made.